# Calling NestJs methods for typings through proxy methods at client side

Tags: node.js, ajax, typescript, axios, nestjs

I am using Nest.js for server-side methods.

I have `document-controller.ts` as below.

```js
@Controller('Document')
export class DocumentController {

@Post('saveMetadata')
  async saveMetadata(metadata: any) {
  // Saving Data On Server. Here when referred through client side it should call ajax method.

  }
}
```

Currently from the client side, I am calling it as below.

```js
import { DocumentController } from 'document-controller.ts';
// Here I need to refer DocumentController.saveMetadata(data) instead of the below string version of the ajax call which through proxy can call the server-side method.
Axios.post(`Document/saveMetadata`, data);
```

Now whenever `saveMetadata` method data changes, I have to find all the references of that method through the string 'saveMetadata' and update it. Possibly I might forget to update someplace.

Is there a way I can directly refer to that server-side nest js method and through the proxy call the ajax method inside that instead of the string version of the ajax call which looks like a tightly bound method virtually?